# UnauthorizedAccessException in HttpDiagnosticProvider - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to trace network calls in UWP.
I am trying to use [HttpDiagnosticProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.diagnostics.httpdiagnosticprovider). Here's my code.

```
var processDiagnosticsInfo = ProcessDiagnosticInfo.GetForCurrentProcess();
var httpDiagnosticProvider = HttpDiagnosticProvider.CreateFromProcessDiagnosticInfo(processDiagnosticsInfo);
httpDiagnosticProvider.ResponseReceived += OnResponseReceived;
httpDiagnosticProvider.Start();
```

I'm getting UnauthorizedAccessException in [Start()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.diagnostics.httpdiagnosticprovider.start#Windows_Web_Http_Diagnostics_HttpDiagnosticProvider_Start) method. What's wrong with my code or do i need to get user grant or something to make it work?

Comment: Have you enabled `internetClient` capatibility in `app.manifest`?

Comment: Yes. It is checked

Comment: @Razor I could reproduce your issue I will discuss with related team.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Any update?

Comment: I have not received the reply , If I get some info I will update below at first time.

Comment: One thing to try as a workaround is add the appDiagnostics capability to the manifest and activate it with [AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestAccessAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.appdiagnosticinfo.requestaccessasync#Windows_System_AppDiagnosticInfo_RequestAccessAsync).

Comment: I've tried that already and it doesnt work.

Comment: Did you check windows event viewer to see if you are getting any exceptions?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Any update on this?